# PHP How to stay on same page after another form has been processed?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So on this application I'm working on, it searches for some code in my database, grabs it, opens a new page and places the code (where necessary) onto the new page by getting its id.

Now within that code (from the database) there is another form that is processed based on user's input. The problem that I am getting is that the new form is not processed on the same page. It redirects to a new url that doesn't specify the code from the database. For example...

When the new page is generated with the code from the database, the url looks like this...

```
localhost/newpage.php?id=1
```

Then when I submit the form within the code from the database it changes to this...

```
localhost/newpage.php?input1=blah&input2=blah
```

But I want something like this...

```
localhost/newpage.php?id=1&input1=blah&input2=blah
```

Just FYI this code needs to be dynamic. For example, let's say I don't know what id the user is looking for and within that id I don't know how many input fields there are.

If you guys need some explicit code (obviously I left out the unnecessary things)...

This is searchpage.php which searches db and displays all relevant items. Then the user selects an item which contains an id and generates newpage.php with that id...

```
//there is a search query then puts all elements in an associative array
$rows = items->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   echo "<a href='newpage.php?id=$id>User clicks to generate a newpage</a>"; 
}
```

This is the form retrieved from database and placed in newpage.php...

```
<form action="newpage.php" method="GET">
   <input name="input1"></input>
   //there can be an x amount of input tags here depending on what id is pulled
</form>
```

This is the php at the top of newpage.php when it is generated...

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   //retrieves data from specified id from database
   if(isset($_GET['inputs'])) {
      //do something with user inputs
   }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this? All help is appreciated! Thanks :)

---

SOLUTION

For this to work, I had to create a session which stores the id. Consequently i had to change all my $_GET varaibles (that dealt with id info) to $_SESSION variables. But it works as long as you're not storing critical/sensitive info!

Here's the code changes...

Changes in search.php ...

```
//there is a search query then puts all elements in an associative array
$rows = items->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['current_id'] = $id;
   echo "<a href='newpage.php?id=$id>User clicks to generate a newpage</a>"; 
}
```

Changes in newpage.php ...

```
<form action="newpage.php?id=" method="POST">
   <input name="input1"></input>
   //there can be an x amount of input tags here depending on what id is pulled
</form>
```

Changes in php of newpage.php ...

```
if (isset($_SESSION['current_id'])) {
   //retrieves data from specified id from database
   if(isset($_POST['inputs'])) {
      //do something with user inputs
   }
}
```

ALL THANKS TO...

Sathik Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the query string "id" in referred header. Either you can attach that query string in client or in server.

Please use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`    to get referer url and from there you can get the id. If it's id of logged in user, I would recommend store them in session for security reason.

Based on your comments,
You can take any one of these actions,
1. Keep the ID in your form as hidden variable
2. Update your url with id as one of the query string and send back to client for error correction.
3. Keep the ID in session, if applicable
4. Use post and perform form validation before redirecting

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is that it changes when i submit the new form. Its not constant. Or am I looking at your solution incorrectly? I'm putting query string within the action of the new form that is generated.

Comment: I forgot to mention this is my post... The form needs to be processed again if there are any mistakes. Your suggestion works but it only once after you submit the form. So if i use http referer that will only work once if i submit the form once. Unless, again, im doing something wrong. I thinking about using POST instead, so it wont change the url.

Comment: Updating the answer again.

Comment: WOOOH!! I kept the id in the session and it works great! Thanks sooo much! I'll update my post with your solution!